# Facebook Comment Count on Comments Plugin

Tags: php, facebook, api, plugins, comments

I run many news sites which use the Facebook comments plugin, e.g.

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.3&xfbml=1&appId={appID}";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

This will display the comment plugin with the total count at the top, *relative to the current site*, not the total comments on all of Facebook. This is the number I'm looking to get.

Now, I want to make a widget on the sites to find their top commented articles. Currently I'm using the ancient REST API like this:

```
$rest_url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls=".$allURLs;
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($rest_url),true);
```

where `$allURLs` is a comma-separated list of article URLs. However, `comment_count` returns the total number of comments all over FB. So if I have an article with 7 comments submitted via the plugin, `comment_count` could be 20, for example, if there are comments elsewhere on FB. I do see `commentsbox_count` in there which looks like what I need, but it's always showing 0.

**So, with a list of URLs on my site and an appID, how could I query Facebook to return the "local" comment count?** I need this via PHP so I can sort the values, so fbml won't work for me.

---

edit - I also tried an FQL query and got the same results:

```
$fql  = "SELECT comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url'";
$fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql);
```

Comment: First of all, stop using `api.facebook.com/restserver.php`, that is deprecated (as is FQL). Use the current API and the endpoints it provides.

Comment: I looked at the docs and didn't find anything like what I want: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/comment -- only `comment_count`

Comment: Further, I don't see a way to pass a URL (or list of URLs) to anything on the new API. Everything seems to be asking for object ids... am I missing something here?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url

Comment: /facepalm Thanks CBroe! I'll try this route and see where I get. Still looks like the only available var is `comment_count` which isn't the right number though. Maybe this isn't possible with the new API?